# How do you force a WPF ListView to Requery its ItemSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, listview, refresh

I'm rewriting its XML itemSource on the fly and want it to use the new data right away...

Comment: I tried this but it didn't do anything..

this.lvwSourceFiles.GetBindingExpression(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty).UpdateSource();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use an ObervableCollection. When this collection is updated, the ListView is updated.

But if for any reason you don´t want to use one, use:

```
listView.InvalidateProperty(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty);
```

or

```
listView.ItemsSource = listView.ItemsSource;
```

Check [A more elegant ListView requery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406542/a-more-elegant-listview-requery) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

hmm...

```
listView.ItemsSource = listView.ItemsSource?
```

or you could trigger the PropertyChanged event on the property of your viewmodel in case you are using MVVM.

Answer (score -1):

ListView.DataBind();
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.databind.aspx)

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried.  

Your answer refers to a System.Web.UI.WebControls ListView, but the WPF ListView is System.Windows.Controls.ListView.