# A more elegant ListView requery

Tags: wpf, listview, refresh

I need to refresh my `ListView` every time the another control's `IsChanged` event is fired. I googled on how to do that, and I saw a stackoverflow link that led me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111338/how-do-you-force-a-wpf-listview-to-requery-its-itemsource)

One of the answers worked:

```
listView.ItemsSource = listView.ItemsSource
```

Is that really the only way to refresh my `ListView`? It feels kinda off.

Comment: Ouch, that is really off. That statement should be a noop. And if it isn't someone will probably think it is and delete it anyway. Dangerous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just invalidate it.

```
listView.InvalidateProperty(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty)
```

That ought to do it.

As an aside, I would really suggest looking at MVVM.  It tends to be much more powerful.  In this case, for an MVVM application, I would just do this:

Xaml:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" />
```

And here would be my ViewModel I'm binding to:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyItems
{
     get; set;
}

public void IsChangedHandler(...)
{
     ...
     this.OnPropertyChanged("MyItems");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your need to refresh the listview each time. It will definitly slow down the performance of your appliction.

It is better to use an ObervableCollection as your listview's ItemSource.

You can find a Thread safe observable collection [here](http://khason.net/blog/thread-safe-observable-collection/).

Also see this question in MSDN Forum - [ListView.ItemsSource: howto update the UI whenever the source is updated?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/1a776eb7-f2a5-4eaa-9e4f-a2c03d570f35)